# Regular Expression: password must contain at least 1 special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to verify that the password inserted by the user has atleast 1 special character in it. Can anyone help me with the regExp?

```
var password = document.getElementById(.....).value;

var special = new RegExp("?????");


if(special.test(password)){


...... 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider all the non-word characters as special characters.

```
var special = new RegExp("^.*?\\W");
```

OR

```
var special = /^.*?\W/;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way.

```
var passwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/);
if (pattern.test(passwd)) {
// code goes here
}
```